# Android Cold Start Time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, splash-screen, cold-start

When opening my app, a white screen shows for about 2 seconds before showing my splash screen which then takes another 2 seconds before going to the main activity. This is really doing some bad UX on my app.

I believe android performs a cold start which displays a dummy white activity before actually showing my splash screen.

I read many posts where users are advising to put `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>` or          `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` in the app theme but this doesn't work for me. It just makes the app looks like it takes more time to load.

However, there are some apps (like Instagram and AliExpress) who bypassed the dummy white activity with their own as shown below:

[image]

Is there a way to replace the dummy white activity with my splash screen ?

If so, can you please share the code or a link that i can refer to please.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565 https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154

Comment: Hello, this actually works thank you. Is there a way to put texts in a layer-list ?

Comment: I think the idea is that your text would be part of the images that you put in the layer-list.

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate the help